# Using def to get the dictionary key to use as a variable

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I want to change value in a variable in a data frame called `'Communication_language_c'` but I don't not want the reference the df column directly. I want to get the variable name from a dictionary key by calling the function name.

```
import pandas as pd

data= [["English"]]
df= pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Communication_Language__c',])

lang= {"English":"ENG", "French":"FR"}

parsing_map={
"Communication_Language__c": lang
}
```

To clarify I want to be able to call `'lang'` from the `'parsing_map'` dictionary to get the dictionary key name `'Communication_language_c'` to then use that to reference the data frame column called `'Communication_language_c'`

I want to use a def function to reference the dictionary `'lang'` to find any value in the Dataframe that is either 'English' or 'French' and switch it to the values in the lang dictionary

How what I make a def function to change the value in `'Communication_language_c'` without referring to the `df['Communication_language_c']` but instead refer to the dictionary function and key value.

Comment: `for k in parsing_map: df[key].str.translate(parsing_map[key])`, assuming you have more keys, otherwise I don't get what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `.replace` like this:

```
df.replace(parsing_map)
```

Additional example for clarification:
If you have a df like this:

```
data = [["English", "English"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Communication_Language__c', 'Communication_Language__d'])
```

You can add an additional key:value pair

```
parsing_map = {
    "Communication_Language__c": {"English": "ENG", "French": "FR"},
    "Communication_Language__d": {"English": "E", "French": "F"},
}

df.replace(parsing_map)

  Communication_Language__c Communication_Language__d
0                       ENG                         E
```

Comment: You can add additional columns in the dictionary